# With DevForce Ideablade, how do I determine if a related entity has been removed from an entity?

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, entity-relationship, devforce

Let's say I have a one-to-many relationship between Person and Pet entities (linked with a simple table with fields PersonID, PetID).  If I do this:

```
aPerson.Pets.Remove(aPet);    
bool result = aPerson.EntityAspect.HasChanges();
```

result is false after the call to HasChanges.  How do I check if a related entity has been removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add/remove a Pet from a Person entity, the Person entity is not itself modified. That's why HasChanges is false.

Try the CollectionChanged event of the Pets navigation property instead:

aPerson.Pets.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Pets_CollectionChanged);